# WordPress Blog Slug Issue

Tags: wordpress, web

Recently I have made a website and since then I am trying to post my new posts on my blog page but it's not showing there.

I have updated settings also where I have made my blog page as a post page.

Whenever I am trying to go to my blog page from my website it is showing index/blog/
And parent directory underneath that.

If anyone can help me in this I would be more than happy.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Permalink is set to Post Name. If not try to set **Post Name** as Permalink from **Settings > Permalink**. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6uQH.png)